# GNOME Resize Window Shortcut like KDE Plasma

Tags: gnome, kde

I've had KDE Plasma and I was able to click super+click to move windows without going to the titlebar and do super+right-click in the general vacinity of a corner of a window to resize it.

You can already do the first shortcut to move windows, but is there a way to do the second?

In detail, what I want to do is to have a shortcut in GNOME where I can resize a window with my mouse in the general area of the corner so I don't have to get my mouse exactly on the edge or corner.

Comment: I don't this this is possible on GNOME but you can use KDE on Ubuntu. The official flavor of Ubuntu with KDE is Kubuntu.

Comment: @Nmath I have KDE Plasma on my machine but I prefer GNOME. I liked the KDE plasma feature but I guess I'll have to deal with it if it's not possible on GNOME. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: The design language of GNOME is "Worse is Better".  So you pretty much have to love it or leave it.

Comment: MATE DE allows to do this with Alt+F8, maybe GNOME still allows the same.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to other DE's like XFCE and KDE, Gnome Shell has no "Window action key" allowing to resize.

It has, like almost all other desktop keys, some traditional keyboard combinations (yes, these existed in Windows 3.1) to move and resize windows. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> enters a "move" modus, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> a resize modus. They allow both fluent mouse and keyboard access for moving and resizing windows.

**<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>: resize**

Hit the key, release it. Now you can drag the mouse in a direction to resize the window. Click, or hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit this "resize" modus. Instead of using the mouse, you also can use the <kbd>arrow</kbd> keys to resize the window.

These keyboard shortcuts can be changed in "Settings", "Keyboard". You can discover some more keyboard shortcuts there.